# Error while inserting row into apache derby database

Tags: java, derby

Following error is happening while inserting a row into Apache Derby
**java.sql.SQLException: Table/View 'FLIGHTS' already exists in Schema 'APP'**. 
Even if the table exists the error is happening while inserting a row into the table 
I have the following simple Apache derby embedded database code :

```
package project;

import java.sql.*;
import java.util.List;

public class Derby {
    public void addFlights(List<Flight> flights) {
        String databaseURL = "jdbc:derby:flightdb;create=true";

        try (Connection conn = DriverManager.getConnection(databaseURL)) {
            Statement statement = conn.createStatement();
            dropTable(statement);
            if (!doesTableExists("flights", conn)) {
                String sql = "CREATE TABLE flights (flightNum varchar(200), airline varchar(200), origin varchar(200), dest varchar(200)," +
                        " departureTime varchar(200), status varchar(200), flightDuration int, aircraft int)";
                statement.execute(sql);
                System.out.println("Created table flights.");
                for (int i = 0; i < flights.size(); i++) {
                    Flight flight = flights.get(i);
                    PreparedStatement preparedStatement = conn.prepareStatement("insert into flights values (?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?)");
                    preparedStatement.setString(1, flight.getFlightNum());
                    preparedStatement.setString(2, flight.getAirline());
                    preparedStatement.setString(3, flight.getOrigin());
                    preparedStatement.setString(4, flight.getDest());
                    preparedStatement.setString(5, flight.getDepartureTime());
                    preparedStatement.setString(6, flight.getStatus().name());
                    preparedStatement.setInt(7, flight.getFlightDuration());
                    preparedStatement.setInt(8, flight.getAircraft().getId());
                    preparedStatement.executeUpdate();
                    statement.execute(sql);
                }
            }

            String sql = "SELECT * FROM flights";
            ResultSet result = statement.executeQuery(sql);

            while (result.next()) {
                System.out.println(result.getString("title"));
            }
            DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:derby:;shutdown=true");

        } catch (SQLException ex) {
            if (ex.getSQLState().equals("XJ015")) {
                System.out.println("Derby shutdown normally");
            } else {
                ex.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }

    private void dropTable(Statement statement) throws SQLException {
//        String sql = "drop table flights";
//        statement.execute(sql);

    }

    private static boolean doesTableExists(String tableName, Connection conn)
            throws SQLException {
        DatabaseMetaData meta = conn.getMetaData();
        ResultSet result = meta.getTables(null, null, tableName.toUpperCase(), null);

        return result.next();
    }
}
```

The error is happening in the line `statement.execute(sql)` line inside the for loop
This is happening the first time this is getting executed. What could be the reason for this ?

Comment: Are you certain that your database framework is not already creating this table?

Comment: Thanks. I got it. `statement.execute(sql);` This line was extra which was causing the trouble. Is there a way to browse the database created by apache derby through some online tool etc

Comment: For browsing your DB, check out SquirrelSQL.